# Nano: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib

Tags: error-handling, reference, dyld, nano

```
$ nano error.log 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/nano
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could not find any solution.
Installing clean homebrew and clean nano did it, tho.

Uninstall homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Install homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install Nano

```
brew install nano
```